(OUTDATED) Looking for workaround for Parity Vault (Parity Signer) not supporting DOT people chain
Disregard, PR was published today...
https://github.com/novasamatech/parity-signer/issues/812
we are looking to update our DOT sub IDs.  We have been a long time Parity Vault (Parity Signer) user. Unfortunately Parity Vault does not currently support DOT People chain. Is there a way to get around this?  We tried restoring our seed to a Ledger but it looks like Parity Vault and Ledger use different account derivation schemes.
Any work arounds? Or are we stuck waiting for Parity Vault to support DOT People chain?
